# Example tensor representation

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products

Studying from Roman's Advanced Linear Algebra I got stuck with the following exercie,
 I want to find two vector spaces $U$ and $V$ and a nonzero vector $x\in U \otimes V$  that has at least two distinct(not including order of the terms) representations of the form:

$$x= \sum _{i=1}^{n} u_i \otimes v_i$$

where the $u_i$ and $v_i$ are linearly  independet in $U$ and $V$.

Comment: which exercise is this in Roman?

Comment: Exercise 13 in chapter 14

Comment: Thanks! I hope you have more questions, these are fun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will do: take $U = \Bbb R^2, V = \Bbb R^2$. We have
$$
e_1 \otimes e_1 + (e_1 + e_2) \otimes e_2 = 
e_1 \otimes (e_1 + e_2) + e_2 \otimes e_2
$$
Or, a more interesting example
$$
(e_1 + e_2) \otimes e_1 + (e_1 - e_2) \otimes e_2 =
e_1 \otimes(e_1 + e_2) + e_2\otimes (e_1 - e_2)
$$

Comment: Ok, but, we have to compare different LI sets in $U$ and $V$. Both of these examples involve distinct sets of $u_i$ for $U$ and $V$... maybe this is inevitable? Otherwise, a given basis has uniquely determined coefficients and while this is not a basis for the whole tensor product it does cover some sort of diagonal.

Comment: @JamesS.Cook for a fixed basis $\{u_i\}$ of $U$, each element of $U \otimes V$ has a unique representation
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n u_i \otimes x_i
$$
with $x_i \in V$.